# Kafka Streams DSL foreach vs process

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I'm implementing the logic for rebuilding a file paginated to several kafka messages with the same key. Every time a page is received its content is appended to the corresponding file in a shared volume and, once the last page is appended, the topology has to include some extra processing steps.

1. Should this be done with *[forEach](https://kafka.apache.org/31/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/KStream.html#foreach(org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.ForeachAction))* or with *[process](https://kafka.apache.org/31/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/KStream.html#process(org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.api.ProcessorSupplier,java.lang.String...))*?
2. Both *forEach* and *process* have void type, how can then be added the final extra steps to the topology?

Comment: **Update:** Kafka supports since version 3.3 _[process](https://kafka.apache.org/34/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/KStream.html#process(org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.api.ProcessorSupplier,java.lang.String...))_ with return type and not only as a terminal action, so several _process_ can be chained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both accomplish the same goal. `foreach` is a terminal action of the DSL, however

`process` method of the Processor API "returns" data to next Processors by *forwarding it to the Context*, as answered in your last question, not via the process method itself

Comment: The goal of this question is to compare both _foreach_ and _process_ methods of Kafka Streams DSL, not with the _process_ method of the processor API. I added the reference URLs to the methods to be compared but maybe my question wasn't clear enough, I'll edit the title.

Comment: I think you misunderstand, `process` requires a `ProcessorSupplier`, which comes from the ProcessorAPI (`org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.api`). Meanwhile, `forEach`, internally makes its own ProcessSupplier, and is a shortcut